# Reading .text() from XML not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have this code that is all working in FF, except for the variable populated by a `.text()` method in IE.

The example code is below:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).find('f').each(function(){

                 var ff= $(this).attr("m");  
                 var fmsg = $(this).text();   

 alert(ff + ' - ' +fmsg); 

 });
 </script>
```

The data (document):

```
 <data>
   <f m="1">hi</f>
   <f m="2">bye</f>
 </data>
```

Why is the alert not showing '1 - hi' and '2 - bye', instead its showing an empty value for the `fmsg` variable. Any suggestions? Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dtuce/1/

Comment: I wouldn't rely on jQuery handling a XML document the browser tried to parse as HTML correctly – it could be confused when trying to apply various browser incompatibility fixes. Try to parse it using [`$.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Comment: Also, the jsFiddle example works for me, another indication that it's your browser's parser at fault.

Comment: Doesn't work in IE only it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The `jQuery#text` method doesn't really seem to be prepared to gather text content from XML from what I could see. (I'd gladly take pointers, though)

```
text: function( text ) {
    if ( jQuery.isFunction(text) ) {
        return this.each(function(i) {
            var self = jQuery( this );

            self.text( text.call(this, i, self.text()) );
        });
    }

    if ( typeof text !== "object" && text !== undefined ) {
        return this.empty().append( (this[0] && this[0].ownerDocument || document).createTextNode( text ) );
    }

    return jQuery.text( this );
}
```

There is -- as always -- a difference between the W3 adherent browsers and IE. The W3 compliant browsers expose the `Node#textContent` property, while IE exposes the `Node#innerText` property.

---

- [MDN documentation for Node#textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent)

---

HTH,

FK